# Rails fetch title tag from HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, title

In my Rails controller, I have a URL that the user provides. I would like to extract the title from the `<title>...</title>` tag in the HTML of that URL, and assign it to a variable `title`. How can I do that?

EDIT: It would be a plus to do it without use of external package/library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tried it with [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to fetch the document, and [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse it:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(HTTParty.get("http://www.google.com").body).title
#=> "Google"
```

Updated:

This works with [Net:HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), which is part of the ruby standard library, and a regex:

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://twitter.com")) =~ /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/
$1 # get the first result from the matching
#=> "Twitter"
```

Updated:

`=~` called "match" is a method on `String` and is used to match a regular expression against a String. It's basically the same as `Regexp#match` but the receiver and argument are inverted.

```
string = "<title>my title</title>
regexp = /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/

string =~ regexp
$1 # => "my title"

regexp.match(string)
$1 # => "my title"
```

What happens when the HTML document you fetch does not contain a title, or title tag?

```
"<title></title>" =~ regexp
$1 # => ""

"" =~ regexp
$1 # => nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I might try that later, but it would be nice if I can do it without use of external package/library.

Comment: Thank you, the Net:HTTP solution seems to work. Could you explain what the `=~` part does? Also, what happens if the page contains no `<title>` tag?

Comment: Ok it's clear now :) By the way, I tried putting `<title>The   new home</title>`, but the `$1` variable has value `The new home`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: (In the `<title>` tag, I had several spaces between "The" and "new", but Stackoverflow won't display as that.)

Comment: Just tried it, and it works with keeping all the spaces. The regular expression and the matcher don't remove it, sorry I have no idea what could be causing the problem.